# How to print unicode characters in the header (YAML) section of a knitr document?

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

This is the YAML header of an RMarkdown IEEE `rticle` I'm writing in RStudio.

```
---
title: Analysis of the impact of ...
author:
  - name: First Lást
    affiliation: xx
    department: yy
    location: zz
    email: aa
abstract: |
  This study aims to investigate ...

bibliography: mybibfile.bib
output: rticles::ieee_article
csl: ieee.csl
---
```

In the `author` section, the `á` will not get printed when converted to PDF with `knitr`

I've tried with different combinations such as  `\u{á}`, `$\á$` and even `\u0225` (the [unicode](https://emw3.com/unicode-accents.html) for that character) without any luck.

How does one include special characters in that section so they are properly displayed when converted to PDF?

Answer (score 1):

I think you nearly had it. Try using the `$\'{a}$` LaTeX command. It worked in RStudio for me. You can find some documentation for LaTex special characters [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Special_Characters).

Comment: alternatively, you could also try with `--latex-engine xelatex`

Comment: How would you print a [soft hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen) that way? Is that even possible?

Comment: Place `\-` in the place where you would like the soft hyphen. See this [LaTeX Wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Text_Formatting#Hyphenation) for details.